# Multiple bxsliders on one page with custom controls

Tags: jquery, bxslider

i have a problem with multiple bxsliders on one page

when a slider has more slides than a different slider, die slider with less slides drops dead. its not working. what i want is that my custom controls only react on one slider. 
this is my html

```
<!-- slider 1 -->
<ul class="bxslider">
    <li>Slide 1</li>
    <li>Slide 2</li>
    <li>Slide 3</li>
</ul>

<!-- slider 2 -->    
<ul class="bxslider">
    <li>Slide 1</li>
    <li>Slide 2</li>
    <li>Slide 3</li>
    <li>Slide 4</li>
</ul>

<div class='customconrols'>
    <a data-slide-index="0" >0</a>
    <a data-slide-index="1" >1</a>
    <a data-slide-index="2" >2</a>
</div>

<div class='customconrols'>
    <a data-slide-index="0" >0</a>
    <a data-slide-index="1" >1</a>
    <a data-slide-index="2" >2</a>
    <a data-slide-index="3" >3</a>
</div>
```

here my jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  pagerCustom: '.customconrols'
});
```

});

i have made a jsfiddle to explain it better

thanks!
http://jsfiddle.net/VLpKK/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found it out myself!
i didn't want to interrupt with the css of bxslider so i added a unique class to each slider like

```
<ul class="bxslider 1">
```

because my customcontrols where auto generated and i couldn't add a class to them id did it with jquery

```
$('.pictures').each(function(i,j) {
   $(this).addClass('custom'+(i+1));
});
```

so now my customcontrols look like this

```
<div class='customcontrols custom1'>
```

Than it was simple linking

```
$('.1').bxSlider({
  pagerCustom: '.custom1'
});
  $('.2').bxSlider({
  pagerCustom: '.custom2'
});
```

Thanks anyway!

Comment: Classes name can't start with a number!

Answer (score 0):

in my case all pager has class `bx-pager`
and all slider has class `slider-call`
and both sliders and pager has a parent with class `iso-content`

```
$('.slider-call').each(function (i,j) {
        let class_name='custom-slider'+(i+1)
        $(this).addClass(class_name);
        let parent=$(this).closest('.iso-content');

        let $child_pager=parent.children('.bx-pager')
        $($child_pager).attr('id',class_name)

        $('.'+class_name).bxSlider({
            pagerCustom: $($child_pager)
        });

    })
```

thanks to answer @steinb